# A couple of series questions that I just can't figure out (Calc 2)

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, factorial

> Show that
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2\left[\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n}t\ dt-\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n+2}t\ dt\right]&=\frac{\pi^3}{8}\left[\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}-\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n+2)!!}\right]\\[10pt]
> &=\frac{\pi^3}{8}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n+2)!!}
> \end{align}
> $$
>   Deduce that
>   $$
> 0<\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}I_{2n}\le\frac{\pi^3}{8}\frac{1}{2n+2}
> $$

I am working on an assignment which requires me to show that 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}
$$
These are the last two parts that I cannot for the life of me figure out. If someone could expand it so I can understand it better that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[Photo of problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09kph.png)

[image: FULL PROBLEM1]
[image: FULL PROBLEM2]

Comment: I would begin by using integration by parts on the second integral on the LHS of question (7).  (This looks similar to, if not the same as something Euler did.)

Comment: Is this really from a Calc 2 class? I'm in the US and my calc 2 class didn't come close to this.

Comment: Yes I think this is similar to Eulers method but not quite it. Not really sure how I should even start the integration by parts. Yes its from a calc 2 class, this is the hardest thing I've had to do so far.

Comment: Can you show us full problem?

Comment: @joetango this is far above any Calc 2 class I have ever seen.  What this reminded me of is what I wrote about in my Master's Thesis.  See pages 33-35 (numbered pages) http://thescholarship.ecu.edu/bitstream/handle/10342/4703/Molokach_ecu_0600O_11345.pdf?sequence=1

Also, I am wondering if you are a Calc 2 student if you even know what the double factorial means?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial

Comment: @Ovi It's indeed Calc 2 from where I come from. It's just part of   Integration Techniques: Integration by Parts and Integrals Involving Trig Functions

Comment: @See-WooLee I added the full problem. Yes this is calc 2 techniques but just very advanced. We never went over double factorials, but I am learning about it as I work on this.

Comment: If I had given this assignment, and if I learned some group had obtained external help contrary to (implicit?) instruction, I'd be obliged to file a formal report of academic dishonesty. Where I teach, academic dishonesty is a "two strikes, you're out" situation; you get one warning, followed by academic expulsion. The points are, please check with your professor whether asking for help here (or elsewhere) is all right, and if so, be explicit about citing assistance received (by giving user names and URLs, or screenshots).

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you already show that the closed form of this Wallis' integral is $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n}\left(x\right)dx=\frac{\left(2n-1\right)!!}{\left(2n\right)!!}\frac{\pi}{2}\tag{1}
 $$ hence $$\frac{\pi^{2}}{4}\left(\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n}\left(x\right)dx-\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n+2}\left(x\right)dx\right)
 $$ $$=\frac{\pi^{3}}{8}\left(\frac{\left(2n-1\right)!!}{\left(2n\right)!!}-\frac{\left(2n+1\right)!!}{\left(2n+2\right)!!}\right)=\frac{\pi^{3}}{8}\left(\frac{\left(2n-1\right)!!\left(2n+2\right)-\left(2n+1\right)!!}{\left(2n+2\right)!!}\right)
 $$ $$=\frac{\pi^{3}}{8}\left(\frac{\left(2n-1\right)!!\left(2n+2-2n-1\right)}{\left(2n+2\right)!!}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{\pi^{3}}{8}\frac{\left(2n-1\right)!!}{\left(2n+2\right)!!}}\tag{2}
 $$ by the definition of the double factorial. For the second part note that, if $\left|x\right|\leq\frac{\pi}{2}
 $, we have $$x^{2}\leq\frac{\pi^{2}}{4}\sin^{2}\left(x\right)
 $$ so $$\frac{\pi^{2}}{4}\left(\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n}\left(x\right)dx-\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n+2}\left(x\right)dx\right)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n}\left(x\right)\frac{\pi^{2}}{4}\sin^{2}\left(x\right)dx\geq I_{2n}
 $$ hence from $(2)$

> $$I_{2n}\frac{\left(2n\right)!!}{\left(2n-1\right)!!}\leq\frac{\pi^{3}}{8}\frac{\left(2n-1\right)!!}{\left(2n+2\right)!!}\frac{\left(2n\right)!!}{\left(2n-1\right)!!}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi^{3}}{8}\frac{1}{2n+2}}$$

as wanted.